# Find Line containing and replace with

Tags: linux, perl, bash, sed, grep

What would be the easiest way to:

Find the line in a text file containing

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

and replace that line with

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `sed`?

Comment: Have you tried at-least one time to google it?

Comment: `sed -i 's|find|replace|' file`

Comment: Yes and yes. Tried many way to solve this, but none of the ways I've tried can accept spaces when searching or replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -i~ -pe 's|^\s*listen\s*=\s*\K /var/run/php5-fpm\.sock|127.0.0.1:9000|x' file
```

Match `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` line with liberal amount of spaces, but replace only `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` part due `\K` positive look behind (same as `(?<=..)`)

Comment: A little bit of explanation might have done good to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed -i 's|listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock|listen = 127.0.0.1:9000|' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this GNU sed commands,

```
sed -ri 's/.*(listen = ).*/\1127.0.0.1:9000/g' file
```

More accurate,

```
sed -ri 's/^(listen = )\/var\/run\/php5-fpm\.soc$/\1127.0.0.1:9000/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's|/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|127.0.0.1:9000|g;' myfile
```